# is casting char pointer to int pointer a undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

In some source I found the following:

`uint32_t str_hash = *(*uint32_t)"CM1";`

I believe is a undefined behavior because

1. it cast away const
2. type punning

Am I wrong? Are there any other violation?

Comment: Was that supposed to be `*(uint32_t*)"CM1";`?

Comment: *(uint32_t*)"CM1; - would be reject by me in a review because alignment of the char pointer for the c string is not guaranteed. You may end up with a misaligned read. "const" could be added to the cast so it is no longer cast away. However 
 the result would be the same. Also I would expect four chars (assuming a simple 8 bit char platform.) There is a forth char in form of a NULL but not convinced this is the programmers intent to use this. Would be undefined behaviour if string was less than 3 chars.

Comment: type punning is not automatically undefined behaviour.

Comment: String constants are not `const` anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Casting `const` away is not undefined behavior: only writing to an object that was declared `const` is undefined behavior.

Unless your platform's `char` type is unsigned, then yes, strict aliasing prohibits dereferencing the pointer, and the behavior is undefined. However, in the real world, given most compilers' general leniency towards type punning, and given that the underlying object is const, it is unlikely to cause issues.

Additionally, in the comments below, davmac raised that `"CM1"` might not be aligned to a `uint32_t`'s required alignment.

The safe way to do this would be to use `memcpy`:

```
uint32_t str_hash;
memcpy(&str_hash, "CM1", sizeof str_hash);
```

With Clang, this [compiles](https://godbolt.org/g/HUaQse) to just one load (which I think is about as good as it can get). There is also no casting away constness, although that wasn't an issue to being with.

Comment: "strict aliasing prohibits this pointer cast" - no, it doesn't prohibit the cast; it prohibits the dereference of the resulting pointer. The cast may be prohibited if alignment is not correct (which it likely won't be for this example), but that's not a strict aliasing issue.

Comment: @davmac, fixed it for you.